# State not changing in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I'm pretty new to react native and having some trouble with setting a new state. Everything works fine until the third textinput shows up, when i start writing inside it the counter is stuck at 1, when it should be at 2, and furthermore update the textInputList too two TextInput elements. I want to understand why the counter does not change, and how to solve this issue:)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import colour from '../constants/Colors';
import StartButton from '../components/Buttons/BackToBackButton';

function ShowNames(props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
            <TextInput
                style = {{ width: '70%', height: 40, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}
                placeholder='Legg in navn her'
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                selectionColor='black'
                onChangeText={props.handleTextChange}
            />
        </View>
    )
}


export default function BackToBack(props) {

    const [nameList, setList] = useState([]);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [textInputList, setInputList] = useState(null)

    const handleTextChange = (text, id) => {
        tempList = nameList
        tempList[id] = text
        setList(tempList)

        if (id == counter) {

            setCounter(counter + 1)
            AddNameInputs()
        }
    }

    function AddNameInputs()
        var tempList = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            console.log('i: ' + i)
            tempList.push(
                <View style={styles.lineContainer} key={i+2}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ width: '70%', height: 40, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}
                        placeholder='Legg in navn her'
                        placeholderTextColor='white'
                        selectionColor='black'
                        onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text, i+2)}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
        setInputList(tempList)

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ShowNames handleTextChange={(text) => handleTextChange(text, 0)} />
            <ShowNames handleTextChange={(text) => handleTextChange(text, 1)} />
            {textInputList}
            <StartButton title={"Start!"} height={100} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: colour.lightTurquoise,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 20
        // borderWidth: 4,
        // borderColor: 'yellow'
    },
    lineContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingBottom: 20

    }

});
```

Comment: in your code you are not opening the AddNameInputs check it once

Comment: yes I am, inside the handleTextChange when id ==counter

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line `tempList = nameList`. It would assume you are referencing the same object when you're setting state and not trigger the relevant updates. So the quickest fix would be to just clone it with the spread operator like `tempList = [...nameList]` ?

Comment: hm i don't think thats the problem, that part of the code give me the expected output. But if you look at the part below when i call handleTextChange